# Writing context free grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I have the following language:

{0<sup>m</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>m</sup> | m,n ≠ 0}

I was wanting to write Context-free grammar for it. I'm a little confused
because the rule doesn't mention that m and n are not equal to each other, so could we treat them in a case as the same?

So could something like

S --> 0S1S0S1S

or

S --> 0101 | 0S10S1 | ε

Comment: They are allowed to be equal, but not required to be.

Comment: First try to write CFG for something simpler like $\{1^n0^n | n >0\}$. Then you can try the language in question.

Comment: @Shreesh for that simpler language, would S --> 01 | 0S1 | ε ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simpler language $\{1^n0^n\ | \ n > 0\}$, we can write grammar as 
$S \rightarrow 1S0\ |\ 10$.

Now we can replace the non-terminal $S$ by $A$. And write context free grammar for the language in the question. $A$ is in the center of $0^m$ and $1^m$. Also remember $m,n > 0$.

$A \rightarrow 1A0 \ | \ 10$
$S \rightarrow 0S1 \ | \ 0A1$